# Horizontal Scroll not working when allocating cell space by percentage

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to show two sections of text occupying the width of available screen and want the sections resized automatically when screen is resized.

I am able to achieve this by assigning width as percentage.  But when the text inside the section exceeds available width for the section, it resizes and no longer follows the percentage allocated.

See the following snippet: If I remove the `white-space: nowrap`, it shows the sections using percentage correctly, but does not show scrollbars, and wraps the text.

It works fine if I allocate width in pixels, but I can't do that because in my application, window is resizable and should resize content for different displays.

The effect I am expecting is:

- Text should not wrap, but should be scrollable horizontally
- The sections should occupy the width of screen according to percentage (35%, 65%)

How can I achieve this?

```css
.Area {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:35%;">
      <div class="Area" id="Area1">
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 1<br>
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 2<br>
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 3<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:65%;">
      <div class="Area" id="Area2">
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 1<br>
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 2<br>
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 3<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: When clicking on "Run code snippet", I am expecting horizontal scroll to appear for both sections. Also the sections should occupy available width according to percentage 35% and 65% (remove `white-space: nowrap` and see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `table-layout:fixed` to your table otherwise your table will always try to resize to fit it's content:

```css
table {table-layout:fixed;}
.Area {
  width:100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:35%;">
      <div class="Area" id="Area1">
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 1<br>
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 2<br>
        hello friends this is cell 1 line 3<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:65%;">
      <div class="Area" id="Area2">
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 1<br>
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 2<br>
        hello friends this is cell 2 line 3<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: I was using `resize:both` css attribute and allowing user to resize the `div`.. after using `table-layout: fixed`, when resizing it overlaps next cell. this is a side-effect. so I removed the resize option.. I guess one can't expect too much :-)..

Comment: hmmm, yeah table cells aren't resizable without a plugin, but what you could do is move the height to your td, give the div a width and height of 100% and then use a plugin to allow the table cell to be resized (then the div will resize with it)

Comment: Yes.. I can see there are so many plugins.. But I am unable to spend time now and don't want to complicate.. As it is I am happy.. Anyway thank u it helps..